# How to set a cookie in ActionBuilder in Play Framework 2.2 / Scala?

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.2

To set a cookie you usually manipulate the result in an action like `Ok().withCookies(…)`.

I created an `AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest]` and need to update the expiry date of a user's cookie by setting a new cookie with a new maxAge sometimes. I cannot figure out how to do this, because I can't find a way to manipulate the result.

Within the `invokeBlock` function I call `block(new AuthenticatedRequest(identity, request))`, which returns a Future[SimpleResult] and I cannot use `withCookies()` on a `Future[SimpleResult]`.

Here's my custom AuthenticatedAction:

```
class AuthenticatedRequest[A](val identity: Identity, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
    def redirectToLogin = {
        Redirect("/login")
    }

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
        request.cookies.get("mycookie").map { cookie =>

            val maybeIdentity = Auth.validateAndTouchTokenAndGetUser(cookie.value)
            maybeIdentity.map { identity =>

                // If it's a persistent session, update timestamp by sending a new cookie sometimes!
                // To simplify this example, assume we always want to set a new cookie.
                val futureResult = block(new MaybeAuthenticatedRequest(maybeIdentity, request))
                // What next?
                val newMaxAge = 1234
                // ???result???.withCookies(Cookie("mycookie", cookie.value, newMaxAge))

            } getOrElse {
                // Respond with redirect to login and delete cookie and a warning message
                Future.successful(
                    redirectToLogin
                    .discardingCookies(DiscardingCookie("mycookie"))
                    .flashing("warning" -> "Your session has expired. Please sign in again.")
                )
            }

        } getOrElse {
            // Respond with redirect to login
            Future.successful(redirectToLogin)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ok` is a `SimpleResult` as well. You cannot set cookies for a `Future[SimpleResult]` but you can do like this:

```
val futureResult: Future[SimpleResult] = ...
futureResult.map(_.withCookies(Cookie("mycookie", cookie.value, newMaxAge))
```

**Update for** `Blankman`:

The simpliest case for responding with cookies is like this:

```
def myAction = Action { 
  ..... 
  Ok(response).withCookies(Cookie("cookie", cookieValue, maxAge)) 
}
```

This way you can compose your more complex Action like this (example from my project):

```
def safe(doSafe: Request[AnyContent] => Future[SimpleResult]): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
  try {
    doSafe(request).map(_.withCookies(Cookie("mycookie", cookie.value, newMaxAge))
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      e.printStackTrace()
      //custom failure response here
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
def someAction = safe { implicit request =>
  .... //something that returns a Future[SimpleResult]
}
```

Comment: @seriejja I have a similiar question but I'm not 100% sure where your snippet should go?  I need to create a cookie from inside my custom Action but not sure.  Do you mind clarifying where to do that?

Comment: Consider a class `F[A]`. Its `map` method would look like this: `def map[B](f: A => B): F[B]`. In short, it passes you a value it holds, lets you transform it and composes a new `F` out of it. In context of `Future[SimpleResult]` `map` waits until the `SimpleResult` is available, adds cookies to the response and returns a cookie-enhanced `Future[SimpleResult]`